# PHP Array or Function - Which is more efficient in this Scenario

Tags: php, performance, function, global-variables

Using PHP 5.6, and will be moving to 7.0 within next 12-18 months on this particular application.

So we have a quite large global config file -- which holds by now close to 100 variables (and each update gets more). As you would expect, this config file is called by every script page in the app, but not all config values are used in all cases -- but for convenience sake, we house them all in the same file.

But I was thinking that perhaps housing the values into functions would be more efficient, but as I am not an architect of the PHP language (or any language), I don't know if using functions is more efficient, less efficient, or pretty much no difference.

So here is an example scenario. In our config file, we have something like this:

```
$g['user']['enable_username_change'] = true;
$g['user']['enable_image_change'] = true;
$g['user']['display'] = "[LASTNAME], [FIRSTNAME]";
$g['user']['sort_by'] = "[LASTNAME]";
$g['user']['default_locale'] = "english";
$g['user']['profile_page'] = file_get_contents('profile_template.html');
```

These values are available to all scripts, but only a handful need them. Obviously we access them by just doing something like this:

```
if ( $g['user']['enable_username_change'] == true ) {
   // the code to enable it ...
}
```

So I was thinking of changing the way this works (if it would create more efficiency) by doing something like this:

```
function user__getGlobalConfig( $in_param_name ) {
    // DEFINE THE VALUES
    $g['user']['enable_username_change'] = true;
    $g['user']['enable_image_change'] = true;
    $g['user']['display'] = "[LASTNAME], [FIRSTNAME]";
    $g['user']['sort_by'] = "[LASTNAME]";
    $g['user']['default_locale'] = "english";
    $g['user']['profile_page'] = file_get_contents('profile_template.html');

    if ( isset( $g['user'][$in_param_name] == true ) {
        return $g['user'][$in_param_name];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then we would access it like this:

```
if ( user__getGlobalConfig('enable_username_change') == true ) {
   // the code to enable it ...
}
```

So it would seem that the file_get_contents() type values would only get read in when function is called, which I believe would be more efficient, but I may be wrong. The other true/false or simple text based values dont seem that they would be a big efficiency gain, but I pose that here -- any science or fact-based reasoning as to why one way would be more efficient than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app currently suffering, or would this be on a whim ?

Comment: Moving your settings variables to function literally __changes nothing__ You still declare the same array of values, now inside a function. And everytime you will call your function - array will be recreated.

Comment: Not suffering necessarily, but as the config file grows, would like to make things as efficient as possible

Comment: @u_mulder right - but if function is not called, then what? Is it more efficient for those scripts that do not need to access those values?

Comment: If function is not called - then nothing happens.

Comment: @u_mulder so in that scenario - it IS more efficient to place inside functions, yes? Or does your original comment stand (that it changes nothing)? My guess is it is more efficient in this context?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the function approach, you should code it so it doesn't recreate the array every time, by using a static variable to cache the settings. In particular, you don't want it to call `file_get_contents()` every time you look up a setting.

```
function user__getGlobalConfig( $in_param_name ) {
    static $g;
    if (!isset($g)) {
        $g = array();
        // DEFINE THE VALUES
        $g['user']['enable_username_change'] = true;
        $g['user']['enable_image_change'] = true;
        $g['user']['display'] = "[LASTNAME], [FIRSTNAME]";
        $g['user']['sort_by'] = "[LASTNAME]";
        $g['user']['default_locale'] = "english";
        $g['user']['profile_page'] = file_get_contents('profile_template.html');
    }
    if ( isset( $g['user'][$in_param_name] ) ){
        return $g['user'][$in_param_name];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```